# List all files and create a copy

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to be able to list all the pdf files in a folder, and create a copy of a survey with the name of each pdf file (bash).

Example 1 : Folder before script execution

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
survey.txt
```

Example 2 : Folder after script execution

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
survey.txt
survey-file1.txt       # a copy of survey.txt
survey-file2.txt       # a copy of survey.txt
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What methods have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd start with

```bsh
for pdf in *.pdf
```

Then, strip off the extension. You can do that with `basename` or with bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Then construct the destination survey file name using the previous step, and do the copy.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Finally i used `for` and the `basename` command instead of trying to used `ls` and `xargs` :

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.pdf
do  
    echo $file
    filename=$(basename -s .pdf $file)
    filename=$(echo survey-$filename)
    echo $filename
    cp survey.txt "$filename".txt
done
```

Comment: You have a "useless echo" there: `filename="survey-$filename"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
for F in *.pdf; do cp survey.txt survey-${F%.pdf}.txt; done
```